# Set owner/user of package when using composer from root

Tags: composer-php

I have composer installed globally on my server.

I have several different domains/accounts on this server.
As root i can ssh onto the server an can use composer to update packages.

However every packages then has the owner and user of root:root. 
When i log in as the account owner I then have insufficient rights to access any of the packages if i need to alter something inside the package.

Is there any way to run composer update and set the user/owner to the account holder other than setup ssh on a per account level?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that if you need to be root to deploy software, then you are doing something wrong.

Composer is no deployment tool, it's a dependency manager. And that's what it does: It will download the required software packages and unzip them to the file system - as the user account that is running the install command.

If you want to change that, you have several options, amongst them things like:

- `su`
- `sudo`
- set group id flag on the directory (`chmod g+s`)
- collect the files outside the server and put them into place via SCP/SFTP/FTPS as the correct user
- not change the dependencies' code as that user, only configuration files
- ... etc.

Comment: Thanks for remembering that `if you need to be root to deploy software, then you are doing something wrong.`